# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'. Already change tf.gfile to tf.io.gfile. but still shown an error

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

with tf.io.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDbge.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2VN8.jpg)

Comment: Did you import 'tf.io.gfile.GFile'?

Comment: Which TensorFlow version are you using? Also please provide minimal reproducible code to replicate the error.